# Auto incrementing ids when jQuery creates the element

Tags: jquery

I have a table that I am creating tr.'s and td's for when the person clicks the button. This is working wonderfully, except I need to be able to add id's to those tr's and have them auto increment.

My full code looks like this

```
 $("#moreRows").click(function () {
     var rowCount = $('table tr').length -1;
     if(rowCount >= 100)
     {
        alert('you have 100 rows');
     }else{
         $("#correctionTable").each(function () {
             var tds = '<tr>';
             jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {

                 tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
             });
             tds += '</tr>';
             if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
                 $('tbody', this).append(tds);
                 $('tbody', this).append(tds);
                 $('tbody', this).append(tds);
                 $('tbody', this).append(tds);
                 $('tbody', this).append(tds);
             } else {
                 $(this).append(tds);
             }
         });
     } 
     return false; 
});
```

and so far I have tried something like this (not the complete each function I know, just an example)

```
var num = 5;
  $("#correctionTable").each(function () {
   var id = num++;
   var tds = '<tr id="'+id+'">';
```

to try and add the id to the original tr within the each loop. This just adds the id of 6 to each tr.

I have also tried this

```
var num = 5;
 $("#correctionTable").each(function () {
   tds = '<tr id="' + (++num) + '">';
```

and this

```
var num = 5;
  $("#correctionTable").each(function () {
  ++num
   tds = '<tr id="' + num + '">';
```

but neither have worked

I have also tried moving that function within the .each function where it is attaching the td to the last tr, but it did not like me adding anything to a variable or replacing that variable to anything else.

Any help would be amazing, I am just plain stuck!

A jsFiddle to show I am not crazy http://jsfiddle.net/bwHnq/33/

Comment: try var id = $(this).find('tr').length;

Comment: Where and why? I am already grabbing the length here... $('table tr').length -1; I'm trying to add an id to the trs...

Comment: You shouldn't use IDs or take care to explain why. As i see it, you just need to delegate click event to table level and then use `event.target` inside handler. This will avoid hundred handlers

Comment: @A.Wolff I don't have a hundred handlers and I need the id's for other reasons than jQuery. I need them for php and style reasons

Comment: @zazvorniki again sorry, i was thinking you want to bind event :(

Comment: @A.Wolff Thats ok, but there are many reasons to want an id on an element. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are never actually increasing the global value of num. Try this:

```
var num = 5;
$("#correctionTable").each(function () {
   num++;
   tds = '<tr id="' + num + '">';
```

Matheus also provides a viable solution. The .length() method will return the number of how many TDs are present within the DOM. You could use the inside of your each statement. Each time the loop occurs it will add a new TD thus increasing the number returned by .length().

Hope it helps!

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/4fs6a/)

Comment: I have already tried this...it just does the same thing and adds 6 to each of the td's instead of counting up

Comment: I'll make a quick fiddle.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I am applying the exact code...it's just not incrementing...

Comment: Its not your exact code, but I can assure it increments the value of num. Check the fiddle. Hope this helps!

Comment: Try putting your num++ inside of the second each statement. I see your num is only increasing with the table, not with each TR/TD.

Comment: Her eis a fiddle with my code... you can see it does not work in this situation http://jsfiddle.net/bwHnq/33/

Comment: Do you want to count the rows or cells?

Comment: I don't want to count them, I'm adding rows and need to add an id to those rows. I can add them to the screen fine, but I can't increment the id.

Answer (score 0):

or

```
var num = 5;
$("#correctionTable").each(function () {
   tds = '<tr id="' + (++num) + '">';
```

Comment: I have also tried this, it does the same as above and just adds an id of six to each of the id's and never counts up

Answer (score 0):

Without using IDs, you could delegate event to TABLE level:

```
$("#correctionTable").on('click','tr',function(e){
    //e.target is the clicked row
    console.log(e.target); //$(e.target) to wrap it inside jQuery
});
```

Comment: i really need the id's for php reasons

Comment: @zazvorniki That's ok, ya sometimes you need IDs for some reason ;) If you are the backend developer, you should then really think about changing server side logic then because here, you'll have hundred handlers bound to hundred elements, not good regarding performance

Comment: Why would I create fields backend when I can do it much easier front end. As long as I have those id's I would be fine so I can send stuff to the database.

Comment: Generally you don't need ID for database request but you know better your code than me for sure

Comment: No, you generally just need a name, but if you have 100 things on the screen it makes it easier to find and target things if you have a unique id.

Comment: @zazvorniki ya for sure :)